# How can I give keyboard focus to a DIV and attach keyboard event handlers to it?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I am building an application where I want to be able to click a rectangle represented by a DIV, and then use the keyboard to move that DIV by listing for keyboard events.

Rather than using an event listener for those keyboard events at the document level, can I listen for keyboard events at the DIV level, perhaps by giving it keyboard focus?

Here's a simplified sample to illustrate the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outer" style="background-color:#eeeeee;padding:10px">
outer

   <div id="inner" style="background-color:#bbbbbb;width:50%;margin:10px;padding:10px;">
   want to be able to focus this element and pick up keypresses
   </div>
</div>

<script language="Javascript">

function onClick()
{
    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML="clicked";
    document.getElementById('inner').focus();

}

//this handler is never called
function onKeypressDiv()
{
    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML="keypress on div";
}

function onKeypressDoc()
{
    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML="keypress on doc";
}

//install event handlers
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListener("keypress", onKeypressDiv, false);
document.addEventListener("keypress", onKeypressDoc, false);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

On clicking the inner DIV I try to give it focus, but subsequent keyboard events are always picked up at the document level, not my DIV level event listener.

Do I simply need to implement an application-specific notion of keyboard focus?

I should add I only need this to work in Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using javascript focus() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Comment: Not really a dupe - it asked some two years prior, and this is asking how to receive keyboard events on arbitrary elements, rather than using the `focus()` function.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Sorted - I added tabindex attribute to the target DIV, which causes it to pick up keyboard events, for example

```
<div id="inner" tabindex="0">
    this div can now have focus and receive keyboard events
</div>
```

Information gleaned from http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS/SCR29.html

Comment: Also, if you don't want the div to get a dotted blue border when it's focused, you can style it `outline: 0px solid tranparent;`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2260788/402807

Comment: Or set `tabindex="-1"`, that will also prevent it from getting the dotted border.

Comment: I can't get this to work at all in Chrome 60 and FF 54. And IE11 magically does the right thing even without the `tabindex`. Is this answer outdated?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in current Firefox. The browser handles the keyboard input. Same for the fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle still works for me - if anyone can reproduce Kwebble's issue I'll update the answer...

Comment: getting rid of the `outline` is not accessible. if you don't like the way it looks, i recommend giving some other visual indication that the element is focused before getting rid of the `outline`

Comment: I just solved this the same way independently - so it's still relevant, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Paul's answer works fine, but you could also use contentEditable, like this...

```
document.getElementById('inner').contentEditable=true;
document.getElementById('inner').focus();
```

Might be preferable in some cases.

Comment: If you do this Chrome 17 puts a cursor on the element on focus and you can type stuff on the element. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @Seppo, that's a good point. If you're consuming the keyboard events then you wouldn't necessarily be able to edit, but having a cursor might be messy depending what you're trying to do. Incidentally, it's not just Chrome 17, but pretty much all recent browsers which behave this way - certainly FF and Safari - IE too I believe, although I've not tested in that lately