# How do I remove the border around a focused contenteditable pre?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

When I set a pre element to contenteditable and put focus in it for editing, it receives a dotted border around it that doesn't look very nice. The border isn't there when focus is somewhere else.
How do I remove that border?

Thanks

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Set the [**`outline` property**](http://w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) to `0px solid transparent;`. You might have to set it on the `:focus` state as well, for example:

```
[contenteditable]:focus {
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: @Christoffer: `outline` will not work in IE7 or lower.  In these browsers, you need to set the `hideFocus` property of the element to `true`, ie `$('#myEl').get().hideFocus = true;`

Comment: For reference: `[contenteditable]:focus { outline: 0px solid transparent; }`

Comment: Thanks all. Saved the day. FYI I'm only seeing the outline on Chrome. Firefox and IE11 don't show it.

Comment: You can also simply use `outline: none`

Comment: Alf, your comment should be marked as the answer :>

Comment: This answer should not have been accepted as it lacks important context about _why_ is that border being displayed there in the first place and gives bad advice (simply removing the default focus style and not providing any replacement).

Answer (score 19):

You can also add the `:read-write` pseudo-class to style elements that are editable.

For instance *([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/morkro/o5f25psf/))*:

```
.element:read-write:focus {
     outline: none;
}
```

Read more [here on codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/read-write/).

> The `:read-write` pseudo-class selector is supported in Chrome, Safari, and Opera 14+, and on iOS.
>   It is supported with the `-moz-` prefix in Firefox in the form `:-moz-read-write`.
>   The `:read-write` selector is not supported in Internet Explorer and on Android.

Comment: What's the difference between this and `.element:focus`?

Comment: It only applies to selectors which are contenteditable.

Comment: Any benefit using that over `[contenteditable]:focus`?

Comment: also :enabled pseudo selector

Comment: This answer fails to provide context about why outline was added by the browser in the first place and doesn't mention that a custom focus style must be provided if the default outline is removed.

Answer (score -2):

Never remove built-in focus styles without providing a replacement, this feature is essential for millions of people who are using the web without a mouse.

An example of good advice on this topic from the HTML Living Standard (
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#element-level-focus-apis):

> [in order to hide the focus ring] use the :focus-visible pseudo-class to override the 'outline' property, and provide a different way to show what element is focused. Be aware that if an alternative focusing style isn't made available, the page will be significantly less usable for people who primarily navigate pages using a keyboard, or those with reduced vision who use focus outlines to help them navigate the page.
>
> For example, to hide the outline from textarea elements and instead use a yellow background to indicate focus, you could use:
>
> `textarea:focus-visible { outline: none; background: yellow; color: black; }`