# Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?

Tags: javascript, focus

Is it possible to focus on a `<div>` using JavaScript `focus()` function?

I have a `<div>` tag

```
<div id="tries">You have 3 tries left</div>
```

I am trying to focus on the above `<div>` using :

```
document.getElementById('tries').focus();
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone suggest something....?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you 'focus' it?  Divs don't accept input, so do you want to flash the border, or flash a background highlight etc?

Comment: @Michael, yes I need that <div> to fetch the attention of user...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: @MichaelShimmins and anyone else, <div> elements can accept input if you have contenteditable set to true. ( Reason why I inquired )

Comment: @MichaelShimmins `div`s can accept input if they overflow and show a scroll bar. When a `div` with a scroll bar is focused, the arrow keys will scroll its content (instead of the content of other elements such as `body`).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
window.location.hash = '#tries';
```

This will scroll to the element in question, essentially "focus"ing it.

Comment: @Casey Chu : Its working fine in ie but not in firefox, do you have any idea ?

Comment: It doesn't work in some Chrome versions...
However, @vinoths solution does it

Comment: This works but... with Angular you would have problems!!

Comment: @CarlosVerdes; Is there a solution for Angular?

Comment: not replying to the 'focus' question, this shouldn't be the correct answer. in my case, I want to focus on an 'contentEditable' div, and your trick doesn't help.

Answer (score 628):

Yes - this is possible. In order to do it, you need to assign a tabindex...

```
<div tabindex="0">Hello World</div>
```

A tabindex of 0 will put the tag "in the natural tab order of the page". A higher number will give it a specific order of priority, where 1 will be the first, 2 second and so on.

You can also give a tabindex of -1, which will make the div only focus-able by script, not the user.

```js
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('scripted').focus();
};
```

```css
div:focus {
    background-color: Aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>Element X (not focusable)</div>
<div tabindex="0">Element Y (user or script focusable)</div>
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted">Element Z (script-only focusable)</div>
<div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```

Obviously, it is a shame to have an element you can focus by script that you can't focus by other input method (especially if a user is keyboard only or similarly constrained). There are also a whole bunch of standard elements that *are* focusable by default and have semantic information baked in to assist users. Use this knowledge wisely.

Comment: And what if in place of <div> tag I am using <td>?

Comment: But this doesn't bring it to the user's attention, it simply makes it tabable.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins, This allows the element to be focusable (in a non-standard way!) with `focus()`.

Comment: IE does not support this :(

Comment: @Babu James - IE definitely does support this. I just tested it in IE8 and it worked fine...

Comment: If you use a negative index (`tabindex="-1"`) then it will not be selectable via the tab key, but you can assign focus to it: http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

Comment: @Olical - I'm pretty sure that's exactly what it says in the last line of may answer. Let me know if you think there is a problem that needs an edit.

Comment: @SteveFenton Oh, so sorry, and that's why you don't skim answers. At least I've added a link to an interesting article on the subject. Sorry about that!

Comment: If it wasn't clear, adding `tabindex` to an element will make it focusable, which enables the `focus()` and `blur()` methods, and then you can trigger a focus like this: `document.getElementById('tries').focus();`

Comment: "But this doesn't bring it to the user's attention" You can style it with CSS using `:focus`. Works on the major browsers, even on MSIE starting with 9.

Comment: and also you can make the outline:0; using css so there will be no difference between simple and tab indexed div

Comment: Thx, now I can focus an element for keyboard-scroll-control: `$('#scrollbykeyboard').attr('tabindex', 0).focus();`

Comment: I appreciate this is an old answer, but giving a div a tabindex of -1 doesn't work in Firefox 42. I had to give it a positive tabindex.

Comment: Hi @SteveOwen - it seems to still work in Firefox v42. I have added a snippet to this answer so you can run it and test.

Comment: Hi @SteveFenton. You're right. I'm sorry. I should have been more specific. I wanted the browser to scroll to the element when it focused on it, and I couldn't get that to work with a tabindex of -1, only when I gave it a positive index.

Comment: @SteveOwen using `window.location.hash = ...` is the way to do that. focus doens't mean "bring into view", it just means literally place the focus on that element.

Comment: But when focused with javascript, the element doesn't seem to get the `:focus` css rules - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: this is such a better answer. @community should mark it instead.

Comment: Firefox 78 seems to allow user focus on elements with a negative tabindex. (Click on Element Z in the example, and you'll see what I mean.)

Answer (score 95):

`document.getElementById('tries').scrollIntoView()` works. This works better than `window.location.hash`  when you have fixed positioning.

Comment: Note that this solution will not work in IE, Opera or Safari.

Comment: I just tried this in Chrome 65 and it does not work. The overlay div scrolls into view, but the focus is still in the background div. The only sure-fire way I know of is to have a tabbable element (using `tabindex` attribute) in the overlay div and use `focus()` on that element instead.

Comment: @om-the-eternity already stated that he wants the div to call the attention of the user, so what he needs is not to actually focus (even when working it's not correct to do it)  the div, but bringing it to the screen, this solves that

Comment: If I do this in Chrome it keeps scrolling back to the still-focused input field. Especially if the page isn't done loading yet.

Answer (score 87):

You can use tabindex

```
<div tabindex="-1"  id="tries"></div>
```

The tabindex value can allow for some interesting behaviour.

- If given a value of "-1", the element can't be tabbed to but focus
  can be given to the element programmatically (using element.focus()).
- If given a value of 0, the element can be focused via the keyboard
  and falls into the tabbing flow of the document. Values greater than
  0 create a priority level with 1 being the most important.

Comment: Life saver, thanks. In Edge a div can be focused but not in Chrome without this trick. Accepted answer is great but I don't want additional part in the url.

Comment: This is def the best answer if you need to do some kinda JS Dom Manipulation for UI. Its really handy for allowing onblur to be used to dismiss elements such as menus or pop up

Answer (score 21):

```
<div id="inner" tabindex="0">
    this div can now have focus and receive keyboard events
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me in Chromium/Chrome 46 only combined with `$('#inner').focus();`

Answer (score 13):

```js
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('scripted').focus();
};
```

```css
div:focus {
    background-color: Aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>Element X (not focusable)</div>
<div tabindex="0">Element Y (user or script focusable)</div>
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted">Element Z (script-only focusable)</div>
<div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but would be good to also add some explanation to your code example.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to suggest something like Michael Shimmin's but without hardcoding things like the element, or the CSS that is applied to it.

I'm only using jQuery for add/remove class, if you don't want to use jquery, you just need a replacement for add/removeClass

--Javascript

```
function highlight(el, durationMs) { 
  el = $(el);
  el.addClass('highlighted');
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.removeClass('highlighted')
  }, durationMs || 1000);
}

highlight(document.getElementById('tries'));
```

--CSS

```
#tries {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#tries.highlighted {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the border flash you can do this:

```
function focusTries() {
    document.getElementById('tries').style.border = 'solid 1px #ff0000;'
    setTimeout ( clearBorder(), 1000 );
}

function clearBorder() {
    document.getElementById('tries').style.border = '';
}
```

This will make the border solid red for 1 second then remove it again.