# How to make HTML element focusable with GWTQuery

Tags: gwt, dom, gwtquery

I am using GWTQuery for low level DOM programming. I have several div elements which need to receive focus so I want to make them focusable. Is there a way to make them focusable with GWTQuery? Or may some other way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is plain GWT (not GWTQuery).

Maybe using something like :

```java
DivElement div = Document().get().createDivElement();
div.scrollIntoView();
```

> This method crawls up the DOM hierarchy, adjusting the scrollLeft and
>      scrollTop properties of each scrollable element to ensure that the
>      specified element is completely in view. It adjusts each scroll position by
>      the minimum amount necessary.

You can also try using tabIndex.

Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656524/921244

Answer (score 0):

none of these work?

```
//Gwt only
DOM.getElementById("myDiv").focus();

//GQuery        
$("#myDiv").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jean-Michel Garcia said, to make a DOM element focusable, you have to use/set the tabindex attribute of this element. The tabindex attribute specifies the tab order of an element and make it focusable.

You can do that using gwtquery :

```
$("#myDiv").attr("tabindex", 1);
```

you can replace the value '1' by any integer you want. It is just the tabbing order of the element (1 is the first). if you set -1, the element can't be tabbed on via the keyboard, but can be focused programmatically using either

```
element.focus();
```

or via GwtQuery :

```
$("#myDiv").focus();
```