# How to use Focus on GWT?

Tags: gwt, focus, onfocus

I have strange problem.. 
I want to do this:

I have a focuspanel. In default I want to give him focus:

```
this.setFocus(true);
```

I have function onBlur which is able to save all information from focuspanel. But the focus panel doesn's have focus... I must click on him, and in other place to start function onBlur..

Second problem is a... When I have focus and I click on other widget **in my focus panel** I lose focus.. (Which I have from click on this panel.) It is not expect.

Only way to save information is to fill it in the focus panel, click on the blank space in focus panel and in other place out focus panel.. I don't know how to fix it..

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

A `FlowPanel` is a `div` and can't have focus by default, you need to set the `tabindex`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656524/66416