# Focus on DIV on Page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using

```
$("#divVZITab").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

On page load I want `divVZITab` to become the focus, it is in the `center` of page. So when page loads IE should automatically scroll to the center of the page & focus on the div.
But it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned IE, I think that is the issue because I tried in jsfiddle and works fine.
I tried in IE with tabindex="-1" and does not work but for positive (+ve) value of tabindex="1" it works. BTW run script after the DOM is ready.

### HTML

```
<div id='divVZITab' tabindex="1">Test</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('divVZITab').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#divVZITab").focus()
```

or

```
document.getElementById('divVZITab').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#divVZITab[tabindex='-1']").focus();
```

Comment: I tried a;; this but all failed...  function setFocus()
    {
    debugger;
    $("#divVZITab").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
    window.location.hash = '#divVZITab'
    document.getElementById('divVZITab').scrollIntoView();
    }

Comment: HI tried..3 solutions.... bt none of them is working!!!!!!!!!!! function setFocus() {  $("#divVZITab").attr("tabindex",-1).focus(); window.location.hash = '#divVZITab'; document.getElementById('divVZITab').scrollIntoView(); }  Please help here

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to focus on a <div> using javascript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function/7208374#7208374)

please refer to second answer in the above link.

Hope that's the same stuff you trying to achieve.