# How to get a <img> tag the focus

Tags: html, css

I have below code in html page:

```
<img id="image_java"  alt="image_not" src="images/java-icon.png">
```

in css page the below code:

```
#image_java: focus {
outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
img:focus{
outline: 2px solid blue;
```

}

but non of them seem to work, they are suppose to display a blue margin around the image when focus.
Does any one know how to do that?  thank you!!!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Actually you CAN focus an `<img>` - with the help of `tabindex`:

```css
img:focus {
    outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function (div and img are not that different in terms of focus).

Comment: Also add a keyboard event handler to the img element.

Answer (score 14):

You can't "focus" an image unless you have an interactive element or navigate to it using tab.  Try adding an interactive element on a wrapper div like so:

Html

```
<a class="imageAnchor" href="#">
    <img id="image_java" alt="image_not" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" />
</a>
```

CSS

```
.imageAnchor:focus img{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4x7wg7sb/1/

Answer (score 1):

If its an anchor tag you can also use

A:focus img{border: 2px solid blue;}

Comment: You should format the code in this answer

Answer (score -5):

Try using the border property instead of the outline property. It should look like:

```
img:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

**Edit:** Use hover instead of focus

Comment: Did you try this before you posted it?

Comment: As they stated below actually, you want to use hover instead of focus.

Comment: Hover is for hovering and Focus is for focusing the clicked element.