# how to access <img tag inside an <a href tag to set focus to <img in IE

Tags: css, image, href

how to access img tag inside a href tag to set focus to `<img>` tag?

eg:

```
<a href ='#' ><img class="img1" src="abc.png"/> </a>
```

The `a .img1:focus {}` didn't work. Not able to access `<img>` inside an `<a href></a>` tag

If I add class to  tag, I can add focus to  tag but  tag &  tag are of diff size & causing issue.                               eg: ,     then a .test:focus{} is working, But I need focus for  tag

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27327765/1531971

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between `a` and `.img1` ( the way you wrote it means "`a` tag with `img1` class" ) this way :

```
a .img1:focus {}
```

This means "element with `img1` class inside `a` tag"

EDIT : in the link @jdv provided in the comments of your initial answer, don't focus (pun unintended) on the accepted answer, but on the second one. You can fix your problem by adding a `tabindex` property to your `img` tag.
Like this :

```
<a href ='#' ><img class="img1" src="abc.png" tabindex="0"/> </a>
```

Comment: What bugs me is the "to set focus to" in your question. What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Css won't "set" any status.

Comment: I have an <img> tag inside <a href> tag. I am trying to get focus(highlight img border with yellow color) when tabbing through <img>, the css a .img1:focus {} is not working                  But If I add class name to < a > tag focus achieved, but <img> & <a href> are of two sizes, the img is shown in bigger size & <a href is focused in smaller size than img  eg: <a href ='#' class="test> <img src="" class ="img1"/></a>, then a .test:focus is working, but I need <img> focus

Comment: Thank you, but it already have focus & tabindex works fine(the page having serial tabindex). My aim is to add highlight img border with yellow color when tabbed &focused

Comment: Well once the css definition works, just add border:4px solid yellow; in it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

try out this code

```
<a href ='#' id='link'><img class="img1" src="abc.png"/> </a>

a#link .img1:focus{}
```

Answer (score 0):

`focus` is often associated with form elements like `input field`  I advise you use `hover` like this instead

```css
a img:hover{
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a><img class="img1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></a>
```

Comment: How about other browsers??

Comment: If I add class to <a href > tag, I can add focus to <a> tag but <a > tag & <img> tag are of diff size & causing issue.   eg:<a href ='#'  class="test"><img class="img1" src="abc.png"/> </a>, then a .test:focus{} is working, But I need focus for <img > tag