# Cancel :active element styling

Tags: javascript, css

I have DOM elements with `:active` CSS styling. If a user makes a click, but never releases the click, I want to be able to cancel the `:active` styling through Javascript.

I have tried doing `document.activeElement.blur()` but that doesn't work when the user does not release the click. (See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ds8wwwL6/).)

How can I force blur an element if the user doesn't release their click?

Comment: Can you give an explanation to why you want to cancel out this behavior?

Comment: @Mouser: Sure. I'm building an iOS app which has a web view, and I want to cancel the `:active` state when dragging. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839517/stop-user-interactions-on-uiwebview) for a full write-up of the problem.

Comment: Seems to be pretty hard core low level to me, almost not cancelable. I'm not a quitter myself, but I think you need to rethink how you set an element "active" state so you can control it yourself. I'm trying some ugly code on the Fiddle and it still wins with a flawless victory.

Comment: Yes, seems very low level. I would be pretty bummed if I had to rewrite all my `:active` styling, especially the default browser styling. I'll add a 500 point bounty if a solution doesn't turn up.

Comment: Not going to post as an answer but this is a difference approach that could save you some time rewriting: http://jsfiddle.net/ds8wwwL6/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@bobdye's** example doesn't work because `<div>` elements aren't "focusable" by default.

You can *force* this behaviour by assigning a `tabindex` property to the div, here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2a74e6tu/).

### HTML

```
<div class="defocus">.::.:.:.::.</div>
<div class="defocus">:..:.:.:..:</div>
<div class="defocus">.::.:.:.::.</div>
```

You add the `class="defocus"` attribute to any element that needs to blur after x seconds.

### CSS (relevant)

```
div:active {
    color:lightcoral;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
(function () {
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var seconds = 0.15 * 1000;
        var defocused = document.getElementsByClassName("defocus");
        for (var i = 0, l = defocused.length; i < l; i++) {
            var el = defocused[i];
            el.style.outline = 0; //optional
            el.setAttribute("tabindex", -1);
            el.addEventListener("mousedown", blur);
        }

        function blur(e) {
            var el = e.target;
            setTimeout(function (el) {
                el.blur();
            }, seconds, el);
        }
    });
})();
```

- First we wrap this function in a [**seaf**](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) just as a commodity (it will prevent the blur function and variables from being accessible).
- Then we get all the elements with a `defocus` class.
- Then we iterate over them.

  - First we eliminate the focus outline some browsers use because it looks ugly in a div, but it's up to you.
  - Then we set a `tabindex="-1"`. Using `-1` as an index prevents it from acting as a [**tab break point**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656524/3750762) but allows it to recieve `focus` and `blur` events.
  - Finally we add the `blur()` function to the `mousedown` event which will *defocus* de element after x seconds.
- Then we define the `blur()` function which will take care of *defocusing* the element with a `setTimeout()`.

That's it, hope it helps!

**Note: I don't particularly care for the bounty, keep your rep!**

**Note: Thanks to [@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954940/adam) for pointing out that seaf's variables need the var prefix to prevent them from being global.**

Comment: No prob, glad I could help! :)

Comment: A `seaf` alone doesn't prevent the blur variables from becoming accessible, a `seaf` and the keyword `var` does. For instance, the variables `seconds` and `defocused` in your code are now globals.

Comment: @Adam nice, fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/mw607an7/) a simple example of canceling the active state if the user holds the mouse down for more than 500ms.

It uses a link:

```
<a id="testlink" href="#">Click this</a>
```

styled to be red if active, and this Javascript:

```
var lnk = document.getElementById('testlink');
var mousedown = false;
var timerId = null;

lnk.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    mousedown = true;
    timerId = window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (mousedown) {
            lnk.blur();
        }
    }, 500);
});
lnk.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
});
```

Obviously not customized for your particular case, but a "proof of concept".

Comment: Hum, it seems the `blur()` technique doesn't work for a `div`. (See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mw607an7/4/).)

Comment: Worth noting this has no visual effect in Firefox, though it does change the `document.activeElement`.

Answer (score 0):

to be added to other answers, you may use a transition (delayed or not):http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEXZGB

```css
*:active {
    background: red;
    filter:blur(5px);
    transition: filter 3s 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js'></script>
see me blured if you click too long.
```