# Put the Focus to <Td> table data element after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code that is not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if the action is successful and returns a success message then Only{
         document.getElementById("tabledataid_row").focus();
    }
});
```

Table data content

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tabledataid_row"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to put the focus back to a table data `<td>` after the page has been submitted. For instance, in Struts action submit brings the form back to the top of the screen. I tried using the JavaScript method `focus()`, it works fine with textfield or elements of input type.

But it is not working when I assign an id to the `<td>` element and then pick it up in the form onload/document ready then call the focus() like this as above.

Please note that I have inserted tabindex at various places and this element id has tabindex 4. So, I dont want to change the tabindex to get the focus come to the id. Only the viewable page be shifted in such a manner that the required field gets visiable.

Comment: You can `focus` only `input` elements

Comment: Do you want to scroll to the `td`???

Comment: @Tushar - correct that the reason I am asking how he got to know focus is on td element ??

Comment: Just submit the form to `#tabledataid_row`, the browser will handle the rest. Doing a `<script>location.hash='#tabledataid_row';</script>` on page load should work too I think.

Comment: I have no idea what struts is, that's why I'm only commenting :p -Don't forget to mark dmlittle's answer as the solution if it solved your problem though.

Comment: @yeppe Only the person who downvoted can answer that, but typically you get downvoted for not asking a clear question, asking an off-topic question or showing that you made no effort to research the problem on your own... I would imagine your downvote is from someone who feels that it should be obvious to anyone that you can't set focus on a `<td>` element (which as keizoms answer proves is not correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only focus on `input` elements. What you want to do is make sure the `id` is in the view. You can achieve what you want to do ('focusing' on a HTML element) using `scrollIntoView()`.

`document.getElementById("tabledataid_row").scrollIntoView();`

Comment: Ok it works in firefox let me check it in other browsers...:)

Comment: bingo it works in IE8 ;).. @dmlittle thanks for a quick one!

Answer (score 1):

(stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656524/1222635)

Give the td a tabindex property. This gives it the ability to be focusable.

```
<td id="tabledataid_row" tabindex="-1"></td>
```

update:

Setting the tabindex to -1 makes it only focusable via script, meaning the user cannot tab to it.

Comment: @yeppe I don't quite understand what you mean by reserving tabindex for a separate use, but if you mean you don't want the user to be able to tab through the td, you can set tabindex to -1 and it will only be focusable by a script and not the user via tab.

Comment: @keizom you should edit your answer to add the `-1` option. SO is a great resource for finding solutions to all kinds of problems - but when answering you should remember that a lot of people come here from google or other external sites, so your answer is not only for the OP... having to look through comments to find a possible solution is inconvenient (and comments may even be removed).

Comment: @Mikk3IRo Done. Good advice for the future, thanks