# javascript focus on div element using # id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hash

hello what I want it is simply like in the image below : 
[image]
I want if I add #element1 so the div which have the same id ="element1" so it will get colored somehow , I just want to know what to type on google so I can find a solution because I searched for javascript hash etc but without any success.

Comment: Are you using the same id more than once? If so, ID's should be unique, hence them being ID's.. to Identify a specific element, not a group of elements. To target a group of elements you should assign them with a class name.

Comment: `$("div#element")` Look for "jQuery selectors".

Comment: @Vidul: And the `div` part of that is unnecessary (and slows things down markedly) in 99.999% of use cases. (You only use it when you want the `id` to be ignored if it's not a `div`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't know this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use window.location.hash to get the hash value

so if your hash is #someId23
do something like:

```
if (window.location.hash){
$(window.location.hash).addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function) will help you to focus div, then you can use 'div:focus, div:active' pseudo classes and add some animation there, there are a lot, google it

This is better than jQuery manipulation. Also page performance doesn't affected