# Activate arrow keys when mouse is inside

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scrollable element within a page. The arrows and home, end, page up, page down keys do not work on it until I click the element.

How can I activate those keys automatically without clicking when the mouse pointer is inside of the element and deactivate when outside?

On the element in question, I tried:

```
<div onmouseover="this.focus()">...</div>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Related question: [Is it possible to focus on a div using javascript focus() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a `tabindex` on an element in order for it to be focusable. If you don't want it to be focusable via tabbing (only via hovering and clicking on it), this `tabindex` can also be negative:

```
<div id="scrollable" onmouseover="this.focus();" tabindex="-1">
    <!-- text -->
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szqdz2t2/))

More on `tabindex` at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Good stuff! More info on tabindex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex