# Keeping the expanded box open when a video is played

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an image map that has various points which when clicked, enlarge into boxes. When you click outside the box the enlarged box closes back into it's original point.

**See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnaeaxge/1/)**

Unfortunately, when I embed a video using IFrame and click play on the video, it closes the enlarged box like I have clicked outside the box.

I believe this is because it removes the focus away from `.mappoint` and takes it to IFrame.

My current system is using HTML and CSS only, but I'm happy to expand, I just have very little knowledge in jQuery etc.

I'm properly stuck, what I would like is for the enlarged box to **remain enlarged when I the video is played and paused**. Do you guys know of a solution to my problem?

```css
html 
  color: #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.description {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
}

div,
img,
footer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dff3fd;
}

a:visited {
  color: #dff3fd;
}

li.active a,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered-y {
  position: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 1190px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map > img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #dff3fd;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <div class="distribution-map">


    <button class="map-point" style="top:24%;left:26.5%">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <h2>Another</h2>
          <p>details</p>
          <iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5MgBikgcWnY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:26%;left:49%">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <h2>Another</h2>
          <p>Details...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:27.3%;left:71.4%">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <h2>Another</h2>
          <p>Details...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:63.5%;left:31.5%">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <h2>Another one</h2>
          <p>Details...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:65%;left:56%">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <h2>another one</h2>
          <p>Details...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:68%;left:74%">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <h2>Another</h2>
          <p>Details...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
```

**Any help would be appreciated, cheers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attempt to fix your JSFiddle, I inquired the solutions from this question:

[**Is it possible to focus on a div using javascript focus function - Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

For reference, I'll go through everything I tried on your fiddle:

- I tried adding an `onclick="this.parentNode(x3).focus()"` on your
  iframe, so that the `map-point` button would still retain its focus,
  therefore retain its CSS `:focus` selector.
- Along with the above, I tried adding `tabindex="0"` to your `map-point` button, per the highest voted answer in the link above. Unfortunately, `iframe` focus overrules `tabindex`.
- I tried using `document.getElementById('bad-map-point').scrollIntoView()` from the next highest voted answer, with no success.
- I tried using a `.manualfocus` classname in the fiddle along with ugly JS, but I messed up the CSS more than I fixed it, so I reverted that.

And then, **I found one, nice, tidy, working solution!**

- I added `hover` selectors on your map-points, and it works with the iframe!

---

**Changes:**

```
.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus,
.distribution-map .map-point:hover { //Added :hover

  ...
}
```

And:

```
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:hover .content { //Added :hover

  ...
}
```

---

It's elegant, runs smoothly, and no JavaScript!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps a ton! Can't thank you enough Aaron! It works with iframe now, and it also looks better with the hover feature haha! Thanks for all your hard work, I would never think to add hover! Cheers:D