# Not able to capture focus on desired element by js .focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

When i call `$('#someelement').focus()` it doesn't give any error message but practically not working. When i try to get `document.activeElement` it still returning `body` element.

Below is my console result:

[image]

Comment: `div`'s dont have a `focus` event. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function.

Comment: Share a working demo here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `.focus` for `#IncomeExpense_wrapper` and that is `<div>` and `div` does not have `focus` event, only input elements does.

Can't help further, because you provide no info on what focusing on div must do.

Answer (score -3):

check this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/gHIo7BdVwyEw6NGghpYF?p=preview) it seems to be working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input type="text" />
    <script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
    $('input').focus();
  })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If you want to focus a div. i suggest you use [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/74uXte5Me6It6bb52P3k?p=info). you see, it scrolls down to the div in question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div id="somediv">this is the div</div>
    <script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
    window.location.hash = "#somediv";
  })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP wants to focus a div with `id="IncomeExpense_wrapper"`