# Triggering set focus to 'DIV' using Javascript - NO JQUERY - Angular ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, setfocus

Trigger set focus to "DIV" element on click using Angular directive

```
<a href="#" class="skipToContent" ng-click="showContent()" title="skip-to-main-content">Skip To Main Content</a>


<div class="getFocus" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <span>Am Focused</span> 
</div>
```

When I click on this the link it should shift the focus to the div

To achieve this I wrote this piece of code PSB.

I tried using [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView); also but not sure it'll work in all the browsers and it dint work for me too.

```
$scope.showContent = function() {
    var x = document.querySelector('.skipToContent');
    var y = document.querySelector('.getFocus');
    y.focus();
    console.log(document.activeElement);
});
};
```

Note: We cannot add ids or add classes to DOM.

https://jsfiddle.net/wrajesh/wo7gkm7d/

Comment: Also, `x.addEventListener` is the correct function you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function

Answer (score 2):

The `scrollIntoView` function works in all major browsers (include chrome/firefox/ie>=8), however if you want to attach the `click` event to the element you should use the `addEventListener` function:

```
var x = document.querySelector('.skipToContent');
var y = document.querySelector('.getFocus');
x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  y.scrollIntoView()
});
```

Check this snippet:

```js
var x = document.querySelector('.skipToContent');
var y = document.querySelector('.getFocus');
x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  y.scrollIntoView()
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="skipToContent" title="skip-to-main-content">Skip To Main Content</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="getFocus" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <span>Am Focused</span>
</div>
```

> Note - the `e.preventDefault()` is there to make sure the browser ignores the default behavior of the `click` event on the `a` tag.

Comment: Hi, Dekel. I have edited my question, How do we push this in Angular ng-click?

Comment: Regarding the angular ng-click - i'll look into it

Comment: I gave you 1 up!! :P Thanx in advance

Comment: Worked like a charm!
I used it without a click event:
document.querySelector('.goToClass').scrollIntoView()
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the focus is as easy as calling the [`focus()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on the target DOM element:

```js
document.querySelector('.skipToContent').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.getFocus').focus()
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="skipToContent" title="skip-to-main-content">Skip To Main Content</a>

<div class="getFocus" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <span>Am Focused</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: This very perfect but if you have any idea in doing in this in Angular ng-click? Please do share

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle skip to main content without any JavaScript at all is this:

1. make the skip to link an internal link pointing to the id of the wrapper div you want to skip to.
2. make sure the targeted wrapper div has tabindex="-1" so that it can receive focus.  This will help with screen readers and those using keyboard-only access.

Of course no actual scrolling will happen if the page is too short.  More content, more the chance for scrolling.

```html
<p><a href="#mainContent">Skip to main content</a></p>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">nav item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nav item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nav item three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="mainContent" tabindex="-1">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Here is some content</p>
</div>
```

I have kept the native div:focus styling so that you can see it working but you will want to style that away (only for this div.  keep focus outlines for actionable elements)

Comment: Hi Halters, Thank you for the solution, I cannot add ids or classes to the DOM, Please share some other solution