# Trigger click event on keypress for any focused element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

Is there a default way to trigger a click event anytime enter is pressed on a focused element?

What I am referencing is the differences from pressing enter while focused on a `<button>` vs. pressing enter while focused on a `<div> <li> <span>`, etc. The `<button>` keypress `enter` triggers as expected. However, `<div>` keypress `enter` does nothing. I believe you have to specifically write the event in for that keypress.

```
$('li').click(function() {  
    //toggles something 
});

$("li").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using javascript focus() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Comment: I am not posting this an answer, because it does not answer your question. Instead it answers the problem the spawned your question — mis-use of non-interactive elements. http://adrianroselli.com/2016/01/links-buttons-submits-and-divs-oh-hell.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there a default way to trigger a click event anytime enter is pressed on a focused element?

**There's no solution without javascript.**

Although the `onclick` has a special behavior as [the W3C mentions](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35.html)

> While "onclick" sounds like it is tied to the mouse, **the onclick event is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button**.

this does not work with other elements than links and buttons.

You could be tempted to add `role="button"` to a `div` with a `tabindex="0"`. **This does not work.**

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role) explicitely says that you have to define handler, even with the `button` role.

This is easily understandable as this is a browser feature. When you define `role=link` on an element, you can't right click on it, hoping that it will open your browser context menu. For the same reason, defining the `role=button` attribute won't affect the default behavior. [From this discussion:](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Mar/0385.html)

> ARIA simply conveys the accessibility semantics
>   intended by the author that are conveyed to an assistive technology.

Also do not forget to handle the <kbd>space</kbd> key. [Read Karl Groves article and example about the subject.](http://www.karlgroves.com/2014/11/24/ridiculously-easy-trick-for-keyboard-accessibility/)

Answer (score 8):

If the elements on your page already have click events, and are in the tab order, and you just want to make the enter key trigger a click on whichever element has focus for accessibility, try the following:

```
<head>
  <script>​
  function handleEnter(e){​
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);​
    if (keycode == '13') {​
      document.activeElement.click();​
    }​
  }​
  </script>​
</head>​
​
<body onkeypress="handleEnter(event)">
```

This is especially useful for adding play/pause and making other image based controls accessible in banner ads made with Google Web Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Certain HTML Elements such as `span, li, div` doesn't not have really have a focused state hence the focus won't trigger. What can be done in order to give the element a possible focus state is to add a tabindex and it will work, e.g:

```
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: Never use a `tabindex` value greater than 0. http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html

Comment: Even with tabindex=0 this does not work without specifically intercepting the keyboard event

Comment: +1 to @Adam's comment, You still need to script it no matter what you do. Also, whomever edited the answer to make the `tabindex` 0 instead of 1, good idea.

Comment: What is the problem with tabindex greater than 0?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo It's bad for accessibility and W3C is working on deprecating values > 0.

Answer (score 0):

When I listen for keyboard events on a list, I put the handler on the `<ul>` instead of the `<li>` and it works great.  It might work on the `<li>` as well but your example above sounds like it doesn't.