# How to give focus on specific div class on page load?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set `.focus();` on specific `<div>` on user action. This action will reload the page and after reload I want to set focus this `<div>`.

NOTE:
I could have added HTML but thought screen shot will be much easier.

Following is my HTML structure:
[image]

I tried following but none of these works:

```
    //option - 1
    $(".cart-panel .pickup-delivery-time .cart-msg").focus();
    //option - 2
    $(".pickup-delivery-time .later").find(".cart-msg").focus();
    //option - 3
    window.location.hash = '.cart-msg';
```

Full Code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#map-delivery-addresses button", function() {
  $.publish('delivery_address_selected', { address: this });

  if (!$(".cart-msg").is(":focus")) {
    $(".cart-panel .pickup-delivery-time .cart-msg").focus();
  }

});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post your js for focusing? the more complete version of the js. If your element has tabindex then something like this should work. How did you check if the element is focused or not?

Comment: No codes are always better than screen-shots. Add HTML code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Comment: And see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus

Comment: @Huangism Here is the code. `$(document).on("click", "#map-delivery-addresses button", function() {
      $.publish('delivery_address_selected', { address: this });  

      if (!$(".cart-msg").is(":focus")) {
        $(".cart-panel .pickup-delivery-time .cart-msg").focus();
      }
    });`

Comment: @CSharper you can edit the question and put the code in there

Comment: @Huangism Done.

Comment: @CSharper it looks like you are trying to set focus inside of the click function. If this function reloads the page then it is no wonder nothing is focused. Js is client side and if a page reloads so does the js, so that focus function basically will never execute, well it executes but the page reloads so you won't see anything

Comment: @Huangism Ah I see. That make sense. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @CSharper also see the answer about different focus() between js and jquery

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `focus` is not the same as the Javascript `focus`. The former fires an event but the latter will place the element in focus.

```js
document.getElementById('second').focus()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="first" placeholder="First"></input>
  <input id="second" placeholder="Second"></input>
  <input id="third" placeholder="Third"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works for inputs, however what behaviour are you expecting once the `div` is focused? It may not be perceptible.

Comment: You can set focus on div the same way you are doing for input, the div just needs `tabindex="0"`

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait for the document to be ready first:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
         jQuery("div#name").focus();
    });
```

It won't work 100% of the time, but 99.9% is probably good enough. There are things that can happen that will steal the focus and not much you can do about it.

If you have a complicated UI you want to better integrate that `focus()` call to that environment.

Comment: The OP wants to set focus on an element not trigger the focus event

Comment: That's what calling `focus()` does. It works for me on `<div>` or whatever other tag.