# Cannot focus on element - Selenium, Chrome, Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to go to the drought monitor website and tell it to select to show county data. I am able to get my code to navigate to the website, and it clicks the dropdown, but I cannot get it to type in "county". My code gets to the last line and then give the error: "Cannot focus element".

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm very new to Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Data/DataDownload/ComprehensiveStatistics.aspx')

browser.maximize_window()
dropdown = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*
[@id="dnn_ctr1009_USDMservice_CompStats_2017_aoiType_chosen"]""")
dropdown.click()
dropdown.send_keys('county')
dropdown.submit()
print("I'm done")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sending keys to the `<div>` that *contains* the search `<input>`, rather than to the `<input>` element itself. You'll need to find the `<input>` and send *it* the keys.

(Note: You also don't need to use XPath for something as simple as a lookup by id.)

```py
dropdown = browser.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr1009_USDMservice_CompStats_2017_aoiType_chosen")
dropdown.click()
search = dropdown.find_element_by_tag_name("input")
search.send_keys("county", Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: @pyd, google it. So many solutions available. The question has been asked many times even on SO.

Comment: to "focus" (make visible, scroll into view) a non-input element, see also [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)