# Best way to focus element of any kind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, accessibility

I have the following requirements:

On my webpage there are anchor links for navigation (thinks like `skip to content` etc.). These anchors are supposed to bring the target element into view and focus it. (Focus is important, because else screenreaders don't get positioned correctly. so far my code looks like this:

```
<a href="#content" class="navbtn">Skip to content</a>
<!-- somewhere else...-->
<div id="content" tabindex="-1">
Lorem ipsum...
</div>
<script>

$(".navbtn").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#content").focus();
});

</script>
```

Please note that I'm aware this is hardcoded and I'll change that in the future, but for test purposes I left it to this.

OK, so what does this do?
[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)
the method above was said to focus the div element. Visually I cannot judge, but my screenreader won't move to the element (I'm using VoiceOver in Safari on an iPhone). If the target is a button, a link or any other element which has a tabindex by default, it works fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I got it to wolk with my braille display when pressing the left mode key. I usually use the right mode key to send a double tap event to the phone, but the right one doesn't work. The left one, however, does. I don't know why, to be honest. Double tap onscreen still doesn't work... Either way, no JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tested the following (with no JavaScript) on an iPhone running iOS12, with VoiceOver in Safari:

```
<a href="#content">Skip to content</a>
...
<div id="content" tabindex="-1">Target content...</div>
```

It worked as expected, with focus moving to the target content and VoiceOver announcing "Target content...". Can you describe the steps you're taking when you test in more detail?

Comment: My code looks exactly like yours. I navigate to the link with my braille display, then press the braille display key that equals a double tap. Focus does not move. I'll test using the screen only, however.

Comment: Even when just using the screen, it doesn't work. If I doubletap the link it says "reader available" and that's it, focus does not move (using VO, Safari, iOS 12.1.2)

Comment: Based on the fact you're hearing "Reader available", it may be that the page you're testing on is triggering Safari's [Reader feature](https://www.imore.com/how-use-reader-view-safari-iphone-and-ipad), and it's getting in the way of your interaction?

Comment: Is there some way of avoiding this?

Comment: It's a browser feature, so it'll be up to the user to dismiss it I think.

Comment: Oh geez... Well. I guess I'll just leave VO be, then... Not ideal, but I offer loads of alternative navigation.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing too much work.  By default, an `<a>` will move the focus for you.  However, if the destination element is **not** a natively focusable element, then it must also have `tabindex="-1"` for some browsers (mainly Internet Explorer).  See "[Accessible HTML Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/accessibility/gg701963(v=vs.85)#accessible-html-elements)" in "About Active Accessibility Support" for the reason why.

So your above example will work with simply:

```
<a href="#content" class="navbtn">Skip to content</a>
<!-- somewhere else...-->
<div id="content" tabindex="-1">
Lorem ipsum...
</div>
```

No javascript is needed.  You can test it by using the keyboard to tab to the "Skip to content" link then pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you then press <kbd>tab</kbd> again, the focus should move to whatever focusable element is after your <div>.

If you then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, you will **not** go back to the <div> (which is the behavior you want) because it has `tabindex="-1"` instead of `tabindex="0"`.

I use this pattern all the time in my accessible websites.

**However** (and this is a big "however" and I think is the main point of your question), VoiceOver on iOS (not sure about the Mac) will **not** honor the focus change.  That's a bug (in my opinion) with Apple.  Go to any website that has in-page links and the VoiceOver focus won't move the destination element.  You can see one reference to this problem at https://www.applevis.com/forum/ios-ios-app-discussion/skip-link-issue

Unfortunately, you should write your code using the simple example (no javascript required) and VoiceOver users on iOS will continue to have a problem like they have on all other sites.

Comment: What confuses me (and lead me to the assumption there was a way to work around this), is that on certain pages (for example SELFHTML) focus movement on Anchor links appears to work...

Comment: Hmm, that is strange.  I tried wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppy) and when I selected "Development" (the first item under the table of contents), it moved my VoiceOver focus to the development section correctly.  Wiki does **not** use `tabindex="-1"` so their page does **not** move the focus properly on Internet Explorer.  Perhaps the `tabindex="-1"` is what's causing the problem for VoiceOver.  (**Note**: If you try the wiki url in this comment from iOS, it might take you to the mobile version.  Go to the last link on the page, "desktop", to go to the deskop version to test.)

Comment: I now have divs with and without tabindex and currently none work, regardless whether I doubletap onscreen or use my braille display. But a while ago it definitely worked (with tabindex) when I used the left mode key...

Answer (score 2):

Voiceover on iOS will not honour JavaScript focus changes on most elements that aren't natively focusable regardless of setting tabindex="-1" or tabindex="0". If you need to have shifting focus for iOS then what I have done is add an empty  tag and set the focus to that, it's not the best solution but it's the only one available on iOS for now.

Comment: Empty tag of which kind?

Comment: I use a <button> tag with role="status" so it's not read out as a button. I've read blog posts mentioning that using a large setTimeout or setInterval value works too but I personally could never get that working properly.

Comment: actually testing this further I've found an <object> tag works better since it won't be read out as activateable by Android Talkback

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thank you. Pretty hacky, but might be the best solution available...

Comment: turns out <object> tag locks keyboard focus on desktop so that's no good unless you are targeting specifically mobile. I ended up just going with an <a> tag now, seems to work reasonably well on all platforms. Yes it seems like a lot of accessibility when it comes to complex web applications is hacky, although support for most aria tags is getting better at least.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for checking this. I suspect we'll have to do something like <a id="theId">&#32;</a>, because Internet Explorer doesn't move focus to "empty" links. But THEN we shuld have everyone covered? *looks hopeful*

Comment: For me only this solution worked. I changed `div` with `tabindex="-1"` to `<button>` and it made the VoiceOver put the focus in the intended destination of anchor link. I think it should be accepted as a solution for the question. Additionally, I put on a `button` a `role="presentation"` to stop screen reader from announcing it as "button". It works for VoiceOver on iOS, however not for TalkBack on Android. So I will limit this solution to iOS mobile devices only.

Answer (score 1):

Use tabindex="-1" on the div instead of tabindex="0". It will make the div programmatically focusable, whereas tabindex="0" makes it user focusable (as someone uses the tab key to move through the content). More on [Using the tabindex attribute](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/)

Comment: I read the article you posted and also did more research, but whether it's tabindex="0" or tabindex="-1" - if I click the link, nothing happens. If the target is a button, or link, or the like focus gets moved appropriately... but not if it's a div.

Answer (score 0):

This would always be best:

```
<a href="#content">Skip to content</a>
...
<div id="content" tabindex="-1">Target content...</div>
```

But sometimes you need some extra functionality so I add a keypress to make sure it triggers a click. Keycode 32 is for the space bar and the 13 is for the enter key.

```
$(".navbtn").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#content").focus();
});

$(".navbtn").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 32 || e.which == 13 ){
                $(".navbtn").click();
            }
        });
```

Or you can just have the keypress trigger the focus