# VoiceOver does not react to anchors and changing focus on iOS properly

Tags: javascript, html, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have asked questions like this one [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978096/best-way-to-focus-element-of-any-kind), but I can't find peace of mind until I found a workaround:

VoiceOver on iOS is the **only** screen reader I encountered which doesn't seem to handle anchors and the JavaScript `element.focus()` function correctly.

Check out [my blog](https://blog.tijos-welt.de/en/). There you'll see the classic `skip to content`-link and a `scroll to top`-button. The link is a regular anchor with its target being the div with the id `main`. The button triggers an animation, but as this isn't having the desired ecfect for the blind, I also made it move focus to the `skip to content` link. Double tap on either of the aforementioned controls while VoiceOver is switched on. The focus will not get moved. I tested this in the iOS apps for Safari, Firefox, Google Chrome and iSource.

Now go to any other device, be it android phone, or windows computer. Switch a screen reader on. As far as I could tell, it always worked (tested with Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer).

The HTML for the anchor:

```
<a href="#main" id="top-link">Skip to content</a>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="main" role="main">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The JS for the button:
    document.getElementById('scroll-to-top').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('top-link').focus();
    });

Nothing fancy, right? And no, `tabindex="-1"` on the main div does not fix my anchor problem. What works is if the anchor refers to a link, but there **must** be some visible text in it, something like

```
<a id="anchorTarget">&nbsp;</a>
```

doesn't work. Did anyone stumble upon a good, solid workaround, or will I just have to live with the fact that my anchors/JavaScript focus changing doesn't do anything for VoiceOver users on iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known problem on iOS](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179011).  There's a [blog](https://axesslab.com/skip-links/) that has some hacky workaround solutions but the real onus is on Apple to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected something like that. Can't believe Apple didn't address this yet, as literally any other OS and screen reader I used does it right.