# How to set focus on carousel containing image or a div so that i can navigate using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, antd

I have been working on Ant `Carousel` :- https://ant.design/components/carousel/ .
`Carousel` is placed inside a `Modal`.
I have few children `div`. Initially arrow keys do not work for navigation. If I click on content of div, then they start to work.

But if `div` contains image, when clicked on it focus is not set to carousel, also if there is any other text in that `div` or slide, clicking it sets carousel as focus.

I have tried using `focusOnSelect` of carousel.
Also set refs to Carousel then called `this.xyzRef.current.focus()` on `componentDidMount()` but it gives me

error :- A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html

code :- https://codesandbox.io/s/pmww228ynj

//JSX file

```
export default class ABCD extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    };


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.textInput);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal visible wrapClassName="abc">
        <Carousel
          id="abc"
          ref={this.textInput}
          draggable
          arrows
          dots={false}
          onSelectFocus={true}
          infinite={false}
          focusOnSelect
        >
          <div className="slick-slide">
            <div>
              <img
                alt="ads"
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"
              />
              <h3>Page 1</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Page 2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Page 3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Page 4</h3>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be able to use left and right arrow keys to navigate in carousel

Comment: consider https://stackoverflow.com/q/3656467/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no possible solution for that issue.

And the problem is with antd.

The Carousel in antd is [slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) and it has no way to set focus on the inner element. And had bad accessibility(can't navigate with tab).

[Problem with set focus to inner modal component](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/issues/279)

Comment: Yup figured it out by using window action listener and next() and prev() methods of carousel......

Answer (score 0):

Use next() and prev() methods given in carousel documentation. Also use action listeners to detect arrow key press.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the after slide event, then trigger the carousel's child method with a delay input.current.focus();

Parent:

```html
class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            slide: 0,
            max_slide: 2,
            current_slide_index: 0,
        };
    };

    _nextSlide = (value) =>{
        let slide;
        if( value===null ) slide = this.state.slide + 1;
        else slide = value+1;
        if( slide>=this.state.max_slide ) slide = 0;
        this.setState({slide:slide});
    };

    _onSlid = () =>{
        this.setState({current_slide_index:this.state.slide});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Carousel
                    interval={null}
                    indicators={true}
                    wrap={false}
                    activeIndex={this.state.slide}
                    onSelect={()=>this._nextSlide(null)}
                    onSlid={this._onSlid}
                >
                    <Carousel.Item className="p-3">
                        <StepInput
                            key_for={0}
                            value_key={"first_name"}
                            value_placeholder={"First Name"}
                            label={"What's your first name?"}
                            nextSlide={this._nextSlide}
                            current_slide_index={this.state.current_slide_index}
                            />
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item className="p-3">
                        <StepInput
                            key_for={1}
                            value_key={"last_name"}
                            value_placeholder={"Last Name"}
                            label={"What's your last name?"}
                            nextSlide={this._nextSlide}
                            current_slide_index={this.state.current_slide_index}
                            />
                    </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" onClick={()=>this._nextSlide(null)}>Test</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
}

export default Container;
```

Child:

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class StepInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.input = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
            current_slide_index: this.props.current_slide_index
        };
    };

    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) =>{
        if( nextProps.current_slide_index===this.props.key_for ){
            setTimeout(function() {this.input.current.focus();}.bind(this),300);
        }
        this.setState({current_slide_index:nextProps.current_slide_index});
    }

    handleUserInput = (value) => {
        this.setState({value: value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card m-5">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >{this.props.label}</label>
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                            <input ref={this.input} type="text" value={this.state.value} className="form-control" onChange={e=>this.handleUserInput(e.target.value)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
export default StepInput;
```