# Select element to be scrollable by arrow keys/pageup/pagedown on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with fixed body elements, like

```
[...]
<body>
  <div id="header">[...]</div>
  <div id="main">[...]</div>
</body>
[...]
```

There is `overflow: scroll` on the `#main`, but without clicking it first I am not able to scroll it with my arrow keys or PgUp/PgDn.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Try adding a `tabindex="0"` to it like in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656524/9867451). This will give it the initial focus