# Is it possible autofocus on div by css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible autofocus on div by css ?

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:10px">
    <label for="organizationContainer" class="nmc-label">@Res.GroupStrings.CreateNewGroupOrganization</label>
    <div id="organizationContainer" class="form-control nmc-select" style="width:100%!important;border:0px!important;box-shadow:none!important" autofocus></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `@Res.GroupStrings.CreateNewGroupOrganization` have to do with the question?

Comment: In pure css I doubt it. There seem to be an [autofocus](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) html attribute, however

Comment: This question has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function) already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with Jquery put the following tag in your head section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
</script>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
  $('#YourDivID').focus();
</script>
```

Or On button click

```
<script>

   $('#somebutton').click(function(){
        $('#YourDivID').focus();
   });

</script>
```

Comment: i want use only css or Html  (not use javascript or jquery)