# Hide placeholder text when the element is focused by CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
div:empty:not(:focus):before {
          content: attr(data-text);
      }
      div:focus:before {
          content: "";
      }
```

```html
<div data-text="placeholder text..."></div>
```

The placeholder text is shown by CSS but when I click the div element, placeholder text doesn't get hidden.

What is wrong with this approarch, `div:focus:before`?

Comment: as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656524/3789527) you can add `tabindex="0"` to your `div`

Answer (score 1):

The `:focus` pseudo-class only applies to elements that can receive focus, such as form elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a>`). The `<div>` element in your code cannot receive focus by default, so the `:focus` pseudo-class doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    div:empty:not(:focus):before {
      content: attr(data-text);
    }

    div:focus:before {
      content: "";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div tabindex="0" data-text="placeholder text..."></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code will allow the `<div>` element to receive focus when the user clicks on it or tabs to it using the keyboard. With the `tabindex` attribute set, the `:focus` pseudo-class will work as expected, and the placeholder text will be hidden when the `<div>` element is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div[contenteditable]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: gray; /* You can customize the color */
}

div[contenteditable]:focus:before {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" data-text="placeholder text..."></div>
```

I think this will help as per your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your `<div>` element for `<input>` or `<textarea>` like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text...">

<textarea placeholder="placeholder text..."></textarea>
```

Comment: The div tag in contentEditable so I can't change it to input or textarea.