# How to access a div by pressing tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have implemented something, which looks like this: if a user clicks on a div, a picture changes in another div:

```
<div id="actionDiv" onClick="changePic();">Change Pic</div>
<div id="picHolder"></div>
```

So this text "Change Pic" can easily be accessed by mouse. How do I get focus from tab key  in the text div actionDiv for accessibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I give keyboard focus to a DIV and attach keyboard event handlers to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it)

Comment: I could not find while I was searching.. but seems like this is the right direction.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, but the question seems similar to this one [how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it) and the answer is basically to give the `div` a `tabIndex` attribute, i.e.:

```
<div id="actionDiv" tabIndex="0" onClick="changePic();">Change Pic</div>
```