# How to bind keyboard events to div elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to listen to keyboard events on a DIV element?

My code:

```
​<div id="div" style="height:50px" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<input id="input">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​$('#div,#input').keyup(function(event){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
});​​​​​​
```

Actually, the code triggers only for the input, can I handle it for the div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it/148444#148444 as mentioned in one of the answers..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I give keyboard focus to a DIV and attach keyboard event handlers to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can add a `tabindex` in that `div` to catch keyboard events like this

```
<div id="div" style="height:50px" class="ui-widget-content" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Like [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148444/344304) here.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/nt2Lb/)

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS/SCR29.html)

Comment: Oh maen, you saved my day! I was looking a few days now for an solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Add a `tabindex` and it should work

```
<div id="div" style="height:50px;" class="ui-widget-content" tabindex="1"></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6uzcN/)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a tabindex to the div.

see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w2Y4d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why not place the input inside the div and then simply find $('#input').closest('div') ?

Otherwise, if your example is a pattern of how your inputs relate to your divs then simply $('#input').prev() ?