# Access DOM element from JavaScript and send event to it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have this HTML element

```
<div dir="auto" data-tab="1" contenteditable="true" class="input" data-reactid=".0.$main.5.2.1.1.0.1"></div>
```

and want to access it from JavaScript code then send it mouse click event and then keyboard key-press events .

I have searching a lot and find this question [Is there a way to simulate key presses or a click with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript) 
but I couldn't access the element !
Can anyone help me to find a way to access it from javascript and send it mouse click event and then keyboard key-press events ?

Comment: You''re not going to want to send it a mouse click event, but a focus event. Try `document.getElementById('myID').focus();` and then fire keyboard events

Comment: Thank you @winhowes But there is no Id for this div could you help me to access it please ?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 1):

To access your particular element I could use a querySelector with an attribute that looks unique to me (I'm not sure if that's your reality):

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('[data-reactid=".0.$main.5.2.1.1.0.1"]')
```

Then, to set a focus:

```
myElement.focus();
```

To send a click:

```
myElement.click();
```

Or, to change a background color:

```
myElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex R. could you tell me if it is possible to send keyboard event to a dev ?

Comment: @MuadhProgrammer Do you mean to a `<div>` element?

Comment: Yeh , to a div element @Alex R. and sorry for the typing mistake !

Comment: `myElement.click();` will send the 'click' to your element (`<div>` in this case)

Comment: `myElement.onclick = function() { alert("Hello, World!"); };` will add the 'click' handler to your element.

Comment: Thank you But I asked if it is possible to send keyboard  events to a div ? because the webpage use div as a input text ! Thank you @Alex R.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722635/4955344).