# Angular 2 keyup.enter for div tag

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, keyboard-events

I need to trigger one function from selected div enter key is pressed. I wrote the following code but it's not working.

```
<div class="data_card" *ngIf="!Add.showEdit" (keyup.enter)="myfunction($event)">
<!-- Some content -- >
</div>


myfunction($event){
      $event.preventDefault();
      alert("sadsa");
}
```

How to trigger this function from div enter key is pressed?

Comment: Is there some sort of input element inside that div? How is it supposed to know that you are clicking enter inside that div?

Comment: inside the div no input elements some data only showing in div

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Why there is still no accepted answer?

Answer (score 7):

try this code. does this help. 
**html**

```
<div class="data_card" *ngIf="!Add.showEdit" (keydown)="handleKeyboardEvent($event)">
```

**// component**

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            **// do your code here**
        }
    }
```

Comment: (keydown)="handleKeyboardEvent($event,index)" i need  to pass some other parameter from html . But when i pass value like this i am getting undefined. How can i pass other parameter?

Comment: what you want to pass? input value?

Comment: No there i am using ngfor i need to pass selected div index value

Comment: in your ngFor just add the i = index  and on all your div elements inside event just add the i, you should recieve the event and the index for that div (keydown)="handleKeyboardEvent($event, i)"

Comment: when do we remove the handler?

Comment: this solution is great and can use for many things, also using "event.key" you can get the key name that pressed!

Answer (score 6):

check out this answer. [How to bind keyboard events to div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722589/how-to-bind-keyboard-events-to-div-elements).

use tabindex:
`The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element can take input focus (is focusable)`

Comment: My app developing using angular 2. Is it possible to do with angular 2 stuffs?

Comment: This answer uses JQuery, not Angular 2+.