# tv.ui.button Only responds to mouseclick on pageload

Tags: button, keyboard, google-tv, google-closure

This tv.ui.button only responds to mouseclick when initially loaded, but then responds to keyboard ENTER or mouseclick after it's been clicked at least once. Do I have something wrong here?

HTML

```
<div class="tv-button alert-button" id="test-button">Alert button</div>
```

JS

```
decorateHandler.addClassHandler('alert-button', function(button) {
goog.events.listen(button, tv.ui.Button.EventType.ACTION,
      function() {
        alert('Button clicked.');
        var elementToFocus = goog.dom.getElement('tab1');
        var componentToFocus = tv.ui.getComponentByElement(elementToFocus);
        tv.ui.Document.getInstance().setFocusedComponent(componentToFocus);;
      });
});
```

EDIT: it seems this may be a question about javascript, not closure specifically. I'm posting a new question under the appropriate tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that the button has cursor focus? If not then the "Enter" key event will get handed to the default handler.

Comment: I'm not sure. How is cursor focus defined?

Comment: Have a look at this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it

Comment: I added tabindex=0 like so   <div class="tv-button alert-button" id="test-button" tabindex="0">Alert button</div>    still no luck, it responds to keyboard only after being clicked at least once

Comment: Also, I just tried adding more than one button and it seems that it's not this particular element that's the problem. No tv-buttons work on the page until at least one has been clicked, then all of them work with the keyboard event

Comment: can you try adding this to the bottom of your html
<script>document.getElementById('test-button').focus();</script>

Comment: a college just pointed out that you are trying to set focus on 'tab1' when you should in fact try to set focus on 'test-button' - change the code snippet you provided in your code and let me know.

Comment: The setting focus to tab1 was just to reset the focus to the first item on the page after the button is clicked, but I changed it anyway. I also tried adding your focus script at the end of the page, still nothing. What exactly changes when a mouse click event is registered on a button, with respect to the focus?

Comment: When an element which is focus-able is clicked by a pointer (mouse in this case) then it gains focus (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus), Now in your case I am only able to guess at whats happening but you may want to try finding out what has the default focus on your page - you can use this method (http://www.meeho.net/blog/2010/01/find-out-which-html-element-has-focus-using-javascript/) to discover what may be stealing focus away.

Comment: Well, I fixed it with a semi hack. i used a $('target').click on $(document).ready, which seems to set the focus as if a click event had actually happened. I'm not incredibly happy about it, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it with a semi hack. i used a $('target').click on the button within $(document).ready, which seems to set the focus as if a click event had actually happened