# Handling two divs with keyboard navigation.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dont have enough reps to add an image to what I am trying to do, but I'll try to be as explicit as possible.

I want to create something like this -

```
div "1" selected from left nav, right nav shows A,B,C,D

|'''''''''''''''|''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
|               |                                    1 |
|  |'''''''|    |       |'''''|           |'''''|      |
|  |...1...|    |       |  A  |           |  C  |      |
|               |       |.....|           |.....|      |
|  |'''''''|    |                                      |
|  |...2...|    |                                      |
|               |       |'''''|           |'''''|      |
|  |'''''''|    |       |  B  |           |  D  |      |
|  |...3...|    |       |.....|           |.....|      | 
|               |                                      |
|...............|......................................|

div "2" selected from left nav, right nav shows E,F,G,H

    |'''''''''''''''|''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
    |               |                                    2 |
    |  |'''''''|    |       |'''''|           |'''''|      |
    |  |...1...|    |       |  E  |           |  G  |      |
    |               |       |.....|           |.....|      |
    |  |'''''''|    |                                      |
    |  |...2...|    |                                      |
    |               |       |'''''|           |'''''|      |
    |  |'''''''|    |       |  F  |           |  H  |      |
    |  |...3...|    |       |.....|           |.....|      | 
    |               |                                      |
    |...............|......................................|
```

I am having 2 divs, leftNavigation and rightNavigation.

leftNavigation has 3 divs as buttons. 
Now I want to navigate through this website **only using arrow keys**. (up/down/left/right)

I am able to catch the events using -

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
        break;

        case 38: // up
        break;

        case 39: // right
        break;

        case 40: // down
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

Now my problem is -

How to use these keyboard events in case of handling left and right navigation at the same time?

for eg. when leftNav is in focus, the up/down keys should only select divs from leftNavigation. 
When rightNav is in focus, the up/down keys should select divs only from right nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like what you're after?

```
if($.contains( $('.leftNavigation'), $(':focus')) // left col has focus
else if($.contains( $('.rightNavigation'), $(':focus')) // right col has focus
```

Assuming your columns have classes .leftNavigation and .rightNavigation respectively

Comment: hmm... i can surely use this to put the divs in focus. The question is- When one of the divs is in focus, Does keydown event sticks to just that div? Appreciate your reply and I'm going to try that right away.

Comment: You can stick with your existing keydown handler, and use this code to determine which column is in focus and what action you would like to take

Answer (score 1):

This SO question may help you - adding a tab index to the DIV allows focus to be applied and accept keyboard events.
[SO:How Can I Give Focus to a DIV and Attach Keyboard Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it)