# fire a button with pressing ENTER after coming with TAB to it

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, enter, keycode

there is a button in my code. Apart from using mouse and clicking it, I'd like to fire (pressing ENTER) it after selecting it with TAB.

```
<div id="CloseButton" tabindex="0" onkeypress="return submitOnEnter(blah,event)">Close</div>
```

if it helps:

```
function submitOnEnter(blah,e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    else return true;

    if (keycode == 13) {
        //at this point I need to fire a button w/o using its id
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If someone knows how to do it?

Is it possible to make 'blah' refer to `<div>`, such that I could do:
     `$(blah).click();`

Comment: If you make it a `<button>` instead of a `<div>` you'll find it a lot easier.

Comment: @Pointy I need it to be <div>

Comment: I think it happens anyway - like in a form you can switch to different input boxes using tab and also you can select the submit button with tab and hit enter to submit it.

Comment: @PamioSolanky Nope, just hitting enter doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: You could try http://stackoverflow.com/a/148444/783219

Comment: To answer the part of your question that goes 'Is it possible to make 'blah' refer to <div>, such that I could do: $(blah).click();' - yes it is possible. Use 'this' in the onkeypress definition instead of 'blah'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:

part of HTML, close button is a div element and is a part of a modal window:

```
...
<div class="closeButton">
      <span id="closeSpan" tabindex="0">Close</span>
</div>
...
```

JS, within the ModalWindow class:

```
$(modWin).find("#closeButton").one("click",            
                   this.close).keypress(this.doNothing);

this.close  = function () {
    $("#modalWindow").css("display","none").fadeOut(200).html("");
    $("#modalWindow #closeButton").hide();
    $(window.self.document.body).find("#modalWindow").remove();
}

this.doNothing = function (e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    else return true;

    if (keycode == 13) {
        innerthis.close();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

PS: innerthis is defined within the ModalWindow class as:

```
var innerthis = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

this could work:

```
jQuery(':focus').click()
```