# How to restrict a Primefaces Hotkey to be called only inside a specific div?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1 with JSF. I have some divs that have an add button inside it. I'm wondering if there's a way to set a Primefaces hotkey to be called only when I have the focus in an element that is inside this div (and calls the add function of that button inside the div). Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I don'tthink you can. Think you have to revert to plain jquery like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it/148444#148444 and combine that with a remoteCommand. But it is an interesting request. Maybe filing an issue in the pf issuelist will result in PF adding it

Comment: As @Kukeltje said, your best bet is to use jQuery.
Oleg Varaksin wrote [a great blog post](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.fr/2012/12/register-hotkeys-for-primefaces-dialogs.html) about a similar request.
I will post an answer with the code snippets if you're happy with this solution.