# React application not handling keyboard events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events, redux

I'm trying to listen to keyboard events, either onKeyPress or onKeyDown, and neither handler will fire. I know that 1. My keyboard works and 2. The same handler does work for onClick.

e.g. (using ES6 class syntax for my components)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div
      onKeyPress={function(e){console.log('keypress');}}
      onKeyDown={function(e){console.log('keydown');}}
      onClick={function(e){console.log('click');}}
    >
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Only 'click' logs to the console. Not sure how the error could be coming from outside this component file, but will include more code if necessary.

Comment: Only the element that has "focus" will receive key events. It's likely your `div` element does not have focus.

Comment: Following up, I tried to provide focus to the div by adding the autofocus (autoFocus in jsx, but I also tried just the `autofocus` html5 version). I also tried click on it to focus on it, and still no luck. Thanks for the suggestion though, hopefully I'm closer.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it

Comment: Using the tabindex solution works if i press tab once, but not immediately (setting it to 0). Hm. I think I'll just use window.addEventListener

Comment: does it work when you set the div as the contenteditable=true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onKeyPress event not called in ReactJS render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948234/onkeypress-event-not-called-in-reactjs-render)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class take those function  out inside the class  and then call them on events like onKeyPress etc events

doSomething(){}