# How can I add event handlers to the body element in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying with the `Html.App.beginnerProgram` and I want to add event handlers (`onKeyDown`, etc.) to the `<body>` element.

Unfortunately everything I put in `view` becomes the children of `<body>`. Returning `Html.body` from `view` doesn't do the trick. This code:

```
main = beginnerProgram { model = 0, view = view, update = update }

view model = body [] []

update _ model = model
```

will generate:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <body></body>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, how do I get the control of the `<body>` element?

Comment: I think you can attach `onKeyDown` to div (and put it outer-most element within body).  Can you elaborate on why you have to attach event handlers in body element?

Comment: IIRC, ordinary `<div>`s cannot receive keyboard events unless they have the `tabindex` property and the focus. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361 Besides, hat I want is the control of `<body>` and `<head>`, not a workaround that enables only `onKeyDown`.

Comment: @Minoru can you please explain, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @halfzebra I'm using `Html.App.beginnerProgram` and I want to add event handlers (`onKeyDown`, etc.) to the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Elm renders as a descendant of `<body/>`, you cannot bind event handling to it in the normal Elm way (e.g. `button [ onClick SomeMsg ] []`). Instead you'll have to use ports. And because you're using ports and subscriptions, you will need to use `Html.App.program` rather than `beginnerProgram`.

You'll need a port function inside your port module:

```elm
port bodyKeyPress : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

And then you'll be able to send key presses to that port from javascript:

```javascript
app.ports.bodyKeyPress.send(...);
```

Here's a full example:

#### Main.elm

```elm
port module Main exposing (main)

import Html.App as App
import Html exposing (..)

main = App.program
  { init = init
  , update = update
  , view = view
  , subscriptions = subscriptions
  }

type alias Model = { message : String } 

type Msg = BodyKeyPress String

init = { message = "Press some keys: " } ! []

update msg model =
  case msg of
    BodyKeyPress c ->
      { model | message = model.message ++ c } ! []

view model = text model.message

subscriptions _ =
  bodyKeyPress BodyKeyPress

port bodyKeyPress : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

And the html behind the scenes (assuming you built using `elm make Main.elm --output=Main.js`):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="Main.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();

      document.body.onkeypress = function(e) {
        app.ports.bodyKeyPress.send(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will need to create and handle a port function for every body event you want to send.