# Not able to add @keyup listener to layout component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, keyup

So I have my outer default.vue layout in nuxt architecture. I'my trying to add `@keyup.esc="test"` to outer element of default.vue:

```
<template>
    <div @keyup.esc="test">
        <navigation></navigation>
        <nuxt/>
        <transition name="fade">
            <overlay-modals v-if="showModalLogin || showModalRegister"></overlay-modals>
        </transition>
        <transition name="zoom">
            <div class="modal__outer" v-if="showModalRegister || showModalLogin">
                    <modal-login v-if="showModalLogin"></modal-login>
                    <modal-register v-if="showModalRegister"></modal-register>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
methods: {
    test() {
        alert('come on...');
    },
```

test method is never fired which makes me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyup event will only be detected by the div when the div has focus, so you have to set `tabindex` to make it focusable, and you have to give it focus.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log("Come on");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$el.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" @keyup.esc="test" tabindex="0">
  Here is my div
</div>
```

Comment: Of course. It's just another way to get at the HTML element.

Comment: But it lose focus after I click something that doesn't lay in this default.vue layout.

Comment: That is how focus works. You may need another approach, putting the event handler on the window. It is not clear when the events should be detected and when they should not.

Answer (score 1):

if u look into [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) u will see that @keyup used in inputs. In your case - u are using this to div, and there is no focus on it so keyup will not possible. However u need to add some stuff to make it working. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it)

Comment: Tabindex doesn't help me.